# Testing connectivity using reactive programming

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'd like to make a network status watcher using reactive programming.

Up to now, I've been able to code that:

```
public class NetworkToolEngine : INetworkToolEngine
{

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int connDescription, int ReservedValue);

    private IObservable<bool> connectionAvailable;
    private Exception exception;

    public NetworkToolEngine()
    {            
        this.connectionAvailable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(_ => this.IsConnectionAvailable(ref this.exception));
    }
}
```

In order to check this:

```
this.networkToolEngine.ConnectionAvailable
    .Do(available => (available) ? this.ConnectionAvailable() : this.ConnectionUnavailable());
```

I don't quite to feel good with this code, I don't like to use an `exception` property in order to spread out which problem has been.

What I only want to get is to test whether some servers are available or are reacheable.

So, I'm looking for a bit more elegant way to get it using reactive programing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You posted too little code. What is IsConnectionAvailable? How do you use connectionAvailable field?

Comment: I've changed post. However, I don't want to use this code. I think it's not a good code to get it. The main goal of this example code is to show what I want to get, but without using this code.

Comment: What I only want to get is an elegant solution in order to check connectivity using reactive programming... What to when connectivity is not available, should I throw an exception? How should I catch this exception in order to keep checking connectivity?

Comment: The bool should be enough. If you cant ping your server _for any reason_, log the exception and return false.